# How can I catch unit-test errors outside test.py script?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, gitlab, continuous-integration

I need to run in CI some run_test.py script:

```
import os
os.system("test1.py")
os.system("test2.py")
```

test1.py and test2.py - both unit-test scripts

Even if there is, for example, an ERROR in test1.py, run_test.py is still executed correctly and CI pipeline is successfully passed, though I need it to fail.

Is there any chance to catch test1.py unit-test errors so that CI pipeline will fall?

PS: running test1.py and test2.py independently in CI file doesn't
work, only works by run_test.py script

Comment: why are you doing this? can you not just call `pytest` or something? if not, then don't use os.system - at least use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)

Comment: I'm getting a db error if I simply call test1.py in CI, although if I do something of above mentioned, db setup works correctly and all test scripts work correctly